# I want to upload a JAR to a GitLab package registry

Tags: maven, gradle, gitlab

I have a prebuilt JAR file that I want to upload into a GitLab package registry so it can be using when a build is performed.

This is my first time playing with Maven and uploading so newbie alert here!

In my project in GitLab I do see that there is a section titled "package registry". I assume that I need to upload it there.

I found the following command which I thought might do the trick:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.acme.group -DartifactId=project-name \
-Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="test.jar" \
-Durl=https://gitlab-np-services.com/Ernie/ernie-sandbox-1/-/packages
-DrepositoryId=project-name
```

I have no idea what to put in for "DrepositoryId", "DartifactId". The other field I assumed in what i put.

How do I know what to put in those fields?

I run it and get the following :

```
Uploading to remote-repository: https://gitlab-np.services.com/Ernie/ernie-sandbox-1/-/packages/com/acme/group/project-name/1.2.3/project-name-1.2.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.793 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-01T15:51:09-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.acme.group:project-name:jar:1.2.3 from/to remote-repository (https://gitlab-np-services.com/Ernie/ernie-sandbox-1/-/packages): transfer failed for https://gitlab-np.services.com/Ernie/ernie-sandbox-1/-/packages/com/acme/group/project-name/1.2.3/project-name-1.2.3.jar, status: 422 Unprocessable Entity -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
vanduyne-16mb:ernie-sandbox-1 vanduyer$ -DrepositoryId=project-name 
bash: -DrepositoryId=project-name: command not found
Perhaps I need to allow permissions to upload to that location in GitLab - which I have no clue how to do.
```

Is that even where I should upload it to?

I have tried looking at the Maven sites and other sites for help on how to do this but I can not find something explaining this for a newbie.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems that I will list below.

- First of all, you are missing a `\` at the end of the third line. So, the `-DrepositoryId=project-name` parameter is not passing to the `mvn deploy` command.
- Next, you need to decide which level do you want to deploy the artifact? You can read more about the levels on Gitlab's official documentation ([GitLab endpoint for Maven packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#use-the-gitlab-endpoint-for-maven-packages)). These addresses lead to `/packages/maven`, but you are missing the `/maven` token in the URL. (`https://gitlab-np-services.com/Ernie/ernie-sandbox-1/-/packages`)
- You don't need to pass a `repositoryId` if you didn't configure any `server` inside your `settings.xml` file. If you configured it, then you can use the defined Id. So, Maven can use the configuration from the `settings.xml` file. You can read more about the `repositoryId` on Maven's official documentation: [repositoryId](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#repositoryId)
- The `groupId` and `artifactId` parameters are the required parameters that define how you can import the artifact from the repository. I suggest you use the same groupId and the artifactId configured inside the `pom.xml` file of the artifact. If you deploy a package with `groupId=com.group` and `artifactId=artifact-id` then you can import the artifact to your project like this:

  ```
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.group</groupId>
           <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
           <version>...</version>
       </dependency>
       ...
   </dependencies>
  ```

I suggest read more about deploying to Gitlab's Maven repository since you have to configure the authentication section as well: [Maven packages in the Package Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository)